# With Set Sql Server first query is not returning any thing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Sorry Once again Now i am getting one more issue that the first query is not coming only second query is working and returning please help like I am getting all the column from second query but not anything from first query

```
 WITH set1
    AS (SELECT
      BillCrtDtm,
      BillModDtm,
      Billing.BillingID,
      Billing.BillTotAmt,
    FROM dbo.Billing
    WHERE BillOrgGrpID = @IOrgID
    AND (BillModDtm BETWEEN @ILastUpdDtFrom AND @ILastUpdDtTo)  ORDER BY BillOrgID ASC, BillModDtm ASC OFFSET @ILastRecNum * @PAGE_SIZE ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PAGE_SIZE ROWS ONLY)

   SELECT
      BICrtDtm,
      BIModDtm,
      BillItemID,
      BIItemPrice,
      BIItemName,
      BIItemBuyingPrice,
      BIInvStockMntc,
      BBInvManf
    FROM BillItem
    WHERE BIOrgGrpID = @IOrgID
    AND BIBillID IN (SELECT
      BillingID
    FROM set1)
```

Comment: Sry begin was there but m using wrong syntax...thnx for help by the way

Comment: A CTE doen't need an `END`, it needs a `SELECT` to actually use the `CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I got the ans sorry.....FYI:the columns are edited and taken few in numbers to make it understand

I am posting it for future help

```
WITH set1
AS (SELECT
  BillCrtDtm,
  BillModDtm,
  Billing.BillingID,
  Billing.BillTotAmt,
  BillIsInsPaid

FROM dbo.Billing
WHERE BillOrgGrpID = @IOrgID
AND (BillModDtm BETWEEN @ILastUpdDtFrom AND @ILastUpdDtTo)  ORDER BY BillOrgID ASC, BillModDtm ASC OFFSET @ILastRecNum * @PAGE_SIZE ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PAGE_SIZE ROWS ONLY)

SELECT
  BICrtDtm,
  BIModDtm,
  BillItemID,
  BIItemPrice,
  BIItemName,
  BIItemBuyingPrice,

  BIInvStockMntc,
  BBInvManf
FROM BillItem
WHERE BIOrgGrpID = @IOrgID
AND BIBillID IN (SELECT
  BillingID
FROM set1)
End
```